# Is it possible to check some condition before returning from a do block in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, monads, do-notation

I'm doing something like this

```
do
  xs <- xss
  x <- x
  if x > 3
  return x
```

The line containing the if is giving me a compile error but I'm not really sure about the proper way to write the same thing.

Just to be more clear, in Scala the equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve would be:

```
for {
  xs <- xss
  x <- xs
  if x > 3
  } yield x
```

Comment: replace `if` with `guard`

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: `Variable not in scope: guard :: Int -> Int` . Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: also you might find this helpful: https://wiki.haskell.org/Do_notation_considered_harmful

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr if you want to answer a question, _answer_ it, don't comment, but be sure to actually know the answer. I'm not sure `guard` actually solves the problem here, and anyways any suggestion for `guard` should explain how one can imitate/implement it oneself using `if`. Also, `guard` does not require any package, only a _module_ import (`Control.Monad`).

Comment: @heapOverflow could you briefly explain what exactly that Scala code does, or give a simple concrete example?

Comment: @sorry about the miswording. however, why do you think guard does not solve the issue?

Comment: @leftaroundabout It's the same as `[x | xs <- xss, x <- xs, x > 3]`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Well in this case it is extremely unclear what the problem is.  The OP even posted showing it doesn't solve the problem because there isn't even a monad in use... that or they forgot to use paren such as `guard (x > 3)`.

Comment: What should the result be if x is not > 3? And FYI there isn't really a concept of "before returning" in Haskell. `return` means something entirely different to what you think coming from other languages.

Comment: I agree that naming the function `return` was probably a bad idea (not because of the name itself, but because imperative languages use it for a totally different semantical concept), but `return` actually does not *terminate* the control flow (per se), nor does it mean that it per se returns a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import `Control.Monad` and use `guard`

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

do
  xs <- xss
  x <- xs
  guard (x > 3)
  return x
```

Also, as the final if statement in scala is just a filter, you can write it like this:

```
do
  xs <- xss
  x <- xs
  _ <- filter (>3) [x]
  return x
```

Edit, as per comment. Even better:

```
do
  xs <- xss
  filter (> 3) xs
```

While in Scala you are doomed to use `yield` within a for loop because it's part of a control structure, in Haskell `return` is just a function and you can avoid using it. In general, as monad rules state, `do {someStuff; x <- xs; return x}` = `do {someStuff; xs}`

Comment: Or even even betterer: `do {xs <- xss; filter (> 3) xs}`. It's always unnecessary to write `x <- foo; return x` instead of just `foo`.